# href not working not moving page to linked file

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i used href to link file used this

```
<a href="../index.php" class="navbar-brand" ><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>`
```

when user clicks on logo user will be redirected to link but in my case its not working.

Also tried:

```
<a href="../" class="navbar-brand" ><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
```

can someone help what's wrong in this you can also live demo here http://www.xpoter.in/blog/ just click on logo you can find error

my head tag

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="top-nav">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <!-- Logo Starts -->
                            <a href="../index.php" class="navbar-brand" ><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                            <!-- #Logo Ends -->
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Nav Starts -->
                        <div class="navbar-collapse  collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right scroll">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#works">Home</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- #Nav Ends -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a piece of jQuery on your page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(".scroll a, .navbar-brand, .gototop").click(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 600, 'swing');
           $(".scroll li").removeClass('active');
           $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('active');
        });
});
```

Which fires on click of  `.navbar-brand`, and you are using `event.preventDefault()` which is preventing your link from working